# Mute notification sounds when on a call

Tags: audio, calls

I use a bluetooth earpiece, and whenever I'm on a call, notification sounds play on top of the call audio. The person on the other end can't hear it, but it's very annoying as I usually can't hear them behind the sounds.

I've tried turning down audio completely, but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may help

Go to Setting:

> 1.Sound
>
> 2.Default Notification Sound (None)

[image: "Please check screen shot"].

> Choose the None option!